# Display elements and respective value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, parent, xslt-2.0

I am XSLT beginner, my requirement is getting element and its respective value in table format, I tried but I did not get the expectation, Kindly suggest solution for my requirement.

My input XML is

```
<group>
<elementgroup1>
<element1>value1</element1>
<element2/>
<element3>value3</element3>
</elementgroup1>
<elementgroup2>
<elementsubgroup2>
<element4>value4</element4>
<element5>value5</element5>
</elementsubgroup2>
</elementgroup2>
</group>
```

my xslt is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="table">
    <xsl:attribute name="border" select="'1'"/>
    <xsl:element name="tr">
        <xsl:element name="th">XML Viewer</xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:for-each select="/group//*"> 
        <xsl:call-template name="mytemplate"/> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="mytemplate">
    <xsl:element name="tr">
        <xsl:element name="td">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*"> 
        <xsl:element name="td">
            <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
/xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My required output

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>
Output
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
group
</td>
<td/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
elementgroup1
</td>
<td/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
element1
</td>
<td>
value1
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
element2
</td>
<td/>
</tr>
<td>
element3
</td>
<td>
value3
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

display output
Output should be in table format, please see below

```
Output
group   
elementgroup1   
element1    value1
element2    
element3    value3
.
.
.
go on till end
```

Comment: Would you like to explain your "requirement".

Comment: @Lingamurthy CS, I need to display the all the elements and respective values in table. It is mentioned in My required output.

Comment: What I asked you was to explain the logic behind the transformation of your input to output. There are many ways we can get an output. I don't see anything happening to `value4` and `value5`.

Comment: @LingamurthyCS, Its should be come, I metioned only few lines of output.

Comment: The requirement should be more specific for us to help you... we cant draw a proper relation between your xml and output.

Comment: @CPR43, I have given my xml input, my tried xslt and required output in my question itself. I am sorry If it is not cleared to you or It may be not clearly requested by me. I will try to explain short and simple now, I just need all element names in one column (like group, elementgroup1, element1...etc) and if elements value is available then it should be displayed in second column (empty row,empty row, value1....etc), where empty rows shows there is no element and it should be a parent, the output should be in table format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understand it right, you need a transformation like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <tr>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>            
           <td><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

that produces the following output of your example XML

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>group</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>elementgroup1</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>element1</td>
      <td>value1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>element2</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>element3</td>
      <td>value3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>elementgroup2</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>elementsubgroup2</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>element4</td>
      <td>value4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>element5</td>
      <td>value5</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**= edit =**

to make elements bold that don't include text (you need a CSS span-class `font-bold`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="bold">
            <xsl:value-of select="'font'"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(string-length(normalize-space(text())))">
                <xsl:value-of select="'-bold'"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="{$bold}"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></span></td>            
           <td><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Leu, Its perfectly working, One more additional request, I need to bold the element which do not have the text like group, elementgroup1, elementgroup2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <tr>
          <td>
           <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: its only gives these following output: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><table><tr><td>group</td><td>
    </td></tr></table>

Comment: oh srry .. have made the required changes